# Create an index that guarantees uniqueness between union of two columns

Tags: postgresql

Consider the following table:

```
CREATE TABLE items (
  ident text NOT NULL,
  label_one text NOT NULL,
  label_two text
);
```

Is there a way I could create a uniqueness constraint, on ident and *either* label_one and label_two?

So for example:

This insert would work:

```
INSERT INTO items (ident, label_one, label_two) VALUES ('foo', 'a', 'b')
```

But these inserts would fail:

```
INSERT INTO items (ident, label_one, label_two) VALUES ('foo', 'a', 'x')
```

It can't insert 'a' into label_one, Because label_one already has the value 'a'

```
INSERT INTO items (ident, label_one, label_two) VALUES ('foo', 'b', 'x')
```

It can't insert 'b' into label_one, Because label_two already has the value 'b'

```
INSERT INTO items (ident, label_one, label_two) VALUES ('foo', 'x', 'a')
```

It can't insert 'a' into label_two, Because label_one already has the value 'a'

```
INSERT INTO items (ident, label_one, label_two) VALUES ('foo', 'x', 'b')
```

It can't insert 'b' into label_two, Because label_two already has the value 'b'

Comment: Looks like a wrong data model, numbered columns where both columns actually hold the same type of data. Normalize your data and you won't have this issue at all.

Comment: Indeed, I guess this would be only way. One problem with normalizing, is that `label_one` is required, but `label_two` isn't. If I have these all in one table, then I don't know how I would go about expressing this.

Comment: You can enforce it at the database level -- though a bit cumbersome -- if you are willing to create a secondary *shadow table* for it, and add a pre-insert trigger to insert into this table behind the scenes. This is needed since you want to insert two entries in the index for every inserted row. What database are you using?

Comment: I am using postgres. One solution I was thinking of, was to use a join table of sorts. The join table can reference the "items" table, where one reference is not null and one is nullable.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is basically what *The Impaler* said in a comment:

1. Create a secondary table

```sql
CREATE TABLE items_constraint (
  ident text NOT NULL,
  label text NOT NULL,
  UNIQUE (ident, label)
);
```

2. create a before insert trigger on the original table (pseudo code)

```
insert into constraint(ident, label) values (new.ident, new.label_one);
if ( new.label_two is not null) {
   insert into constraint(ident, label) values (new.ident, new.label_two);
}
```

Of course, all this smell of denormalized data and the problem would probably go away when the data is properly normalized.